# Using a pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child, parent, child-process

I am trying to use a single pipe which creates 3 child processes, where each child procss shouold prompt the user to enter an int and then writes it to the pipe. The parent process should read the pipe and display the largest int.

Here is what I have with my limited knowledge:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main(int argc, char argv[]) {
    int input[3];
    int i;
    int fd[2];
    int result;

    if(pipe(fd) == (-1))
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed\n");

        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if(fork() == 0){//child
                printf("Enter a number: ");
                scanf("%d", &input[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        if(input[0] >= input[1]){
            if(input[0] >= input[2])
                result = input[0];
            else
                result = input[2];
        }
        else if(input[1] >= input[2]){
            if(input[1] >= input[0])
                result = input[1];
            else
                result = input[0];
        }
        else if(input[2] >= input[0]){
            if(input[2] >= input[1])
                result = input[2];
            else
                result = input[1];
        }
        printf("The max of the three is: %d", result);
    }
```

When I try running this in terminal I get this:

```
The max of the three is: 4195760Enter a number: $ Enter a number:
Enter a number:
The max of the three is: 4195760The max of the three is: 4195760Enter a number:
The max of the three is: 4195760
```

Please shed some light on me.

Comment: You need to `write` to the pipe and `read` from the pipe. As it is you are not using the pipe at all and the `input` values you are reading in each process contain garbage. Once the `fork` runs each process has its own independent copy of `input`. That is, what one process writes to `input` is not seen by any of the other processes.

Comment: @AlanAu but how do I actually do that? I have never worked with read/write or pipes before..

Comment: I'm not going to write the program for you. If you don't know anything about pipe/read/write then the manual pages are the place to start. The [pipe manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) even contains an example. Have a read, try out some code and come back with an updated question if you still have difficulties.